# My Wordpress Plugin code breaks customize.php viewpoint

Tags: plugin-development, theme-customizer

I've been making a few tweaks to my plugin to try and get it back up and running with an upgraded API/backend.

Sadly with my latest changes which commented out a few lines, I broke the backend view to customize the widget. I wondered if anyone has seen this before?

My code is on Gitlab if looking at the code helps. It's quite lengthy and not 100% sure where it's breaking at the moment, so not sure which snippet to add.

Current view: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jxrbv.png

Comment: The first step would be to start debugging your code, line by line if needed, to figure out where its breaking.  Once you have that info it should help point you to an answer on how to fix it.  Unfortunately, I think your question as is will be too vague for anyone to give you a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that right-clicking and viewing the source on the web-page displayed the call-stack.

For some reason part of my backend widget code that was commented out was still active, therefore it was trying to complete a request that had missing code. Removing this code resolved the error.